# Disabling (specific) apps from running during sleep in macOS

Tags: macos, battery, sleep-wake, ventura, onedrive

I want to disable some apps from running during sleep (due to unwanted/unnecessary battery consumption). Particularly; I want to disable **Microsoft OneDrive** from running during sleep on a **M2 MacBook Air (Ventura 13.5.1).**

I suppose enabling Low Power Mode would stop it from running, as well as any other background app. A way to automatically enable it just before sleep (and to disable right after wake-up) could be a sub-par but OK fix.

(I get around 2% drop in 12 hrs of sleep, which is sad especially given that I know for sure that there hasn't been any updates, and I could definitely just wait 30 extra seconds after waking my Mac up to receive the updates if there were any; if the updates couldn't be made in the time that I navigate the directory tree to the documents I'm after, that is.)

Is there a direct way to keep Power Nap enabled and influence the power loss of 2% during sleep?

Answer (score 1):

When on battery and Power Nap is enabled, the only functions that are enabled are:

- Messaging Updates
- Calendar Updates
- iCloud Updates

When it's plugged into AC/mains power (though not relevant to this question), it will download updates and perform Time Machine backups.  Your apps aren't running in the background.

See [What is Power Nap on a Mac?](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/what-is-power-nap-mh40773/13.0/mac/13.0) for details.

When your Mac sleeps, applications are paused (not running) and is  similar to an older feature called [App Nap](https://osxdaily.com/2014/05/13/disable-app-nap-mac-os-x/) (Mavericks).  Back then, you could *disable* this state to allow for activity while asleep, but now, it's moot, the apps are paused (setting can't be changed)

> (I get around 2% drop in 12 hrs of sleep, which is sad especially given that I know for sure that there hasn't been any updates,

There are a couple of issues with this:

- First, this is not an issue.  All batteries dissipate charge while dormant.  At this rate, it will take 25 days - the better part of a month - (if left unused) to fully deplete the battery.  This is perfectly normal
- Secondly, you can't be certain there were "no updates" especially if you have App Store apps set to update automatically, whether or not you received messages and what iCloud updates were processed.  Not everything is a major update that you'll be made aware of.

When Power Nap wakes periodically, to check for updates, it uses CPU, power to the WiFi chip **and** power to transmit and receive the radio signal for that WiFi which all consume battery.  If you have a poor connection, it will draw more power thus consuming more battery.

Comment: I think macOS Ventura on M2 does run stuff (other than just the three listed here) while asleep. My Mac has been sleeping for over 12 hrs, and *Activity Monitor > Energy > 12 hr Power* shows that many apps have consumed power (including OneDrive, admittedly isn't the worst offender). Moreover, see https://www.intego.com/mac-security-blog/what-does-your-mac-do-when-its-sleeping/. I feel your take of "not an issue" is inaccurate; my battery would drain less if no task was running during sleep.  That's my issue to solve.

Comment: @UtkanGezer I'm not so sure your drain is due to Power Nap. Have you confirmed this with tests where you disable Power Nap and let it sleep uninterrupted for 48 hours? Then you'll want to repeat the test with it powered off for 48 hours. You should be able to use the console log and inspect each and every item during the sleep periods to confirm what's actually running.